# Magento RestApi-OAuth taking long time to add product

Tags: php, magento, rest, oauth

I am using following code to adding product into magento via restapi
but it's taking 10-20 second to add one product....

```
function saveProduct($data) {
    $this->productData=json_encode($data);
    try{
            $oauthClient=new OAuth($this->consumerKey, $this->consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $this->authType);

            $oauthClient->disableSSLChecks();
            $oauthClient->enableDebug();
            $oauthClient->setToken($this->token, $this->secret);
            $oauthClient->fetch($this->resourceUrl, $this->productData, $this->oauthMethod, $this->headerType);

            $this->responceInfo=$oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo();
            $this->responce=$oauthClient->getLastResponse();

            if(preg_match(PROD_ID_EXT_PTN,$this->responceInfo['headers_recv'],$m))
                $this->productID=$m[1];
        }
        catch(OAuthException$e) {
            $this->oauthError=$e;
        }
}
```

my custom code file [RestApi.php](http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/j94-7yr)